# Async API call returning an array in Angular with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, http, async-await, get

I have a code that shall return a list of products from an API.
Once I retrieve the list I have some logic. I must execute this code as async for other reasons.

First I defined an **Interface Type** that contains the structure of my return type:

```
export interface IProduct {
    id:                            string;
    name:                          string;
    localizedName:                 string;
    isBundle:                      boolean;
}
```

The next function calls the API using http get returning a promise.

```
productInfoAPI(productId: string) {
    let myUrl = 'https://myurl.com/productInfo/' + productId ;
    return this.http.get<[IProduct]>(myUrl).toPromise();
}
```

Finally my main function calls the API asynchronously. I can see the result on the console and also the length of the array returned.

```
async fetchProductInfo() {
    let data = await this.api.productInfoAPI('123');
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data?.length);

    for (let x=0; x < data?.length; x++) {
        console.log(data[x]);
        // my logic here
    }
}
```

However once I try to iterate to the list using a for-loop I get an error.
Typescript says that data?.length may be undefined so I can't compile this code to proceed.

Any suggestion how to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data does `productInfoAPI()` return?

That `?` on `data?.length` means that you are telling TypeScript "the `data` property might not be defined, so please check it for me before you try to access the next property"

For example, this TS code:

```
var data = {
  foo: 'bar'
}

console.log(data?.length);
```

Wil compile to the following JS code:

```js
var data = {
    foo: 'bar'
};
console.log(data === null || data === void 0 ? void 0 : data.length);
```

---

So that that and apply it to your code.  Why is `data` possibly undefined at the point where you want it loop over it?  My guess is that it's not and you should remove that `?`

```
async fetchProductInfo() {
    let data = await this.api.productInfoAPI('123');
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.length);

    for (let x=0; x < data.length; x++) {
        console.log(data[x]);
        // my logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two lines in this code with data?.length.
The console.log line it works and I see no compile error.
The second one does not work and I see the error:
"The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362). 'data.length' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)"

Comment: So what kind of interface/typedef does `data` have?  Please edit your original question to either include that, or a sample of what the response from that method looks like